# Sorting by name after each entry

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I am using this LINQ statement to sort a list by product name (ascending order) which contains product names (`string`) and `Sizes` available for each product (`List<byte>`);

```
LinkedList<FullItemDetails> itemDetails = new LinkedList<FullItemDetails>();  

public class FullItemDetails   
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public List<byte> Sizes { get; set; }
}
```

Now every time I input a new entry ex; `Jacket,6,12,18,10`, I think my program is sorting my list all over again;

```
itemDetails.AddLast(fullItemDetails);

//SortedProducts
itemDetails = Products.OrderBy(x => x.ProductName).ToList();
```

If the list is already sorted I only need to put the last entry in its correct place.
What is the best way to do it. Also to reduce the complexity of the algorithm. thanks

Comment: Depending on how big a set of data you are working with, is it a performance hit to reorder every time? That method has to compare the product names to determine order, and your inserting in the correct place is going to be doing the same. You will have o(N) speed in this case. If the dataset isn't huge, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Are you using a `LinkedList` or a `List`? You declare a `LinkedList` but LINQ returns a `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an ideal problem for a `SortedList`, as you have a key (name) and value (`List<int>` for the size).

Documentation is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx

The list declaration would look like this: `SortedList<string, List<int> >`. All inserts would be sorted on string, and the values can be enumerated based on each key.

Comment: `SortedSet` is probably an even better fit.

Comment: Worked perfect thanks. I read that SortedList uses binary search for searching for a key. The complexity is O(logN). I assume this is the same for inserting a single entry in its correct place.

Comment: SortedList insertion is O(N). Consider using `SortedSet` instead, as jessehouwing noted.

Comment: Both are good, it depends what he needs. If he wants all sizes associated with a particular product name, the SortedList may be better for out of the box functionality. SortedSet coupled with a Tuple may also fit the bill, or even concatenating the candidate values (name + size). Depends on implementation, but upvotes for noting SortedSet :)

Comment: And user..., the big O complexity for insertion is O(n) as Timothy Shields mentioned, because the worst case for insertion is to have to resize the list. However, when inserting into a list that is below capacity, it is only O(logN), as you noted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `List<T>`, use `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` or `SortedSet<T>`. You can pass in an `IComparer<T>` to use a specific sorting algorithm [through the respective constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132323.aspx). [Should you want to use a Lambda expression, you can use a small wrapper class to wrap a `Comparison<T>`](http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.nl/2009/04/converting-comparison-to-icomparer.html).

Which will result in something like:

```
ICollection<FullItemDetails> _itemList = new SortedSet<FullItemDetails>(new ComparisonComparer<FullItemDetails>((x,y) -> x.ProductName.CompareTo(y.ProductName))
```

Your collection will now always be ordered.

When you're using .NET 4.5, you can [use `Comparer<T>.Create` to create an `IComparer` implementation from a lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198.aspx).

Comment: BTW, it's not `SortedList<T>`, it's `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: Thanx, fixed. That's why I also included the SortedSet<T>. SortedList is more like an automated Dictionary than a sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SortedList<string,FullItemDetails>`.

And you add your times like that `list.Add(fullItemDetails.Name,fullItemDetails)`

**[Edit]** : The order will be conserved after adding or removing an element.

**[Edit2]** Using LINQ
you use a list to store your items (adding/removing) : `List<FullItemDetails> originalList` and other property to *read* your sorted data :

```
IEnumerable<FullItemDetails> sortedList = originalList.OrderBy(e => e.Name).ThenBy(e => /* logic to order by another property*/);
```

and now you can iterate through your `sortedList` and as this sorted list is an `IEnumerable<T>` each time you iterate through it you will have exactly the same elements as in your `originalList` (after adding or removing items).

In other words : `sortedList` only contains the logic to read your `originalList`.

Hope this helps.
Regards.

Comment: I am trying to use your method but since each entry will have a list of sizes apart from the name I need to store them aswell. How can I implement your method for the sizes as well?

Comment: In this case I can propose another solution using LINQ (cf. Edit2 on my answer)